# Counting objects in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Django. I would like to count and display the number of objects which satisfy a condition in a template.

I have a User model and Account model. The users have a foreignkey field account, which maps onto an Account object.

In the template, I would like to count the number of users for each account.

The closest I have got is this:

```
{% for account in accounts %}

    {% for user in users %}

        {% if equal user.account.id account.id %}

            {{ user.count }}

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your template, it seems like the user field is defined something like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    .
    .
    account=models.Foreignkey()
    .
```

if it is something like this you could follow [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

```
{% for account in accounts %}
    Count: {{ account.user_set.count }}
    {% for user in account.user_set.all %}
        {{ user }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks. I wonder if this should be done in the Views rather than the templates, then passed as a context?

Comment: Is the account field for your user defined like I proposed?

Comment: Yes, account is a foreignkey of user. I would like to count the number of users per account

Comment: yeah...fixed the answer according to that now

Answer (score 4):

You can annotate your accounts with the user count in the view. Assuming the User model contains `account = ForeignKey(Account, related_name='users')`:

```
accounts = Account.objects.annotate(user_count=models.Count('users'))
```

That way you'll only need a single query. Then simply use the following in your template:

```
{% for account in accounts %}
    {{ account.user_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but got a NameError (global name 'models' not defined.)

Comment: Add this to the top of your python file: `django.db import models`